# I need some help waiting for a thread to end

Tags: android, multithreading

I have this code:

```
jsonObject1=getLocationInfo(direction);
```

It is intended to return a jsonObject, later that will be parsed and I will get lattitude, and longitude.

This is the method:

```
public JSONObject getLocationInfo(final String address) {

            Thread thread=new Thread(){

                public void run(){
                    String adressString=address.replaceAll("\\s+",",");
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    try {



                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + adressString + "&sensor=false");
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response;
                    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


                        response = client.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                        int b;
                        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                        }

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }

                    ;
                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }
            };
            thread.start();

            return jsonObject;
        }
```

The problem is... since that method involves an HttpGet, it must be in another thread. But, just after the thread.start() method, the return jsonObject line is called, so the returned object will be null... how could i wait for the thread to end before returning anything?

Thank you.

Comment: use asynctask it is easier to code.

Comment: You don't need / should not use a thread if you do nothing after starting / while waiting on a thread. You won't get the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` because you are hiding the fact that you block the main thread for http but you are essentially doing it in the main thread because it waits as long as the other thread does the http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), all the network stuff is done in the `doInBackground` and after that is done the method `onPostExecute` gets called so you know when the httpget has finished and do what you need to do there

Comment: My class extends Service, so I can't extend AsyncTask

Comment: you create the AsyncTask as an inner class in your service

Comment: what do you mean? all you do is instead of creating a separate class file just declare the class in your service

Comment: Its gonna be the first time im using AsynkTask...so i have things to read, and test. Thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do this. But if you just want to use threads like above, use a Handler and send data via Handlers.Let me know if you want to see some code.